# Workflow not executing while doing DML inside Platform Event trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, email, workflow, platform-event

I am trying to log all the **exception in a Debug_Log__c object** and send a mail through **workflow (written on Debug_Log__c)** using **platform events**.

When I am using the **platform event trigger** to **insert** the records in **Debug_Log__c** object then the workflow is not getting executed.

Below is my code:

```
public class ResponseHandler extends API.UnTypedResponseHandler{

    protected override Object handleError(){

        //Checking the response code here
        if (this.hr.getStatusCode() == 400) {

            //Getting the record type
            RecordType rt = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Debug_Log__c' AND DeveloperName='sync'];

            //Publishing the event
            EventBus.publish( new Log__e( Log_Type__c = rt.Id, Data__c = 'Request ==> '+this.req+ ' ----- Response ==> '+this.hr));

            //Throwing exception here
            throw Lib_AuraExceptionFactory.create(Lib_AuraExceptionFactory.Cause.callout, 'There was some error syncing the record. The team was informed and they will look into it.');

        } else {
            // go with parent's error handling
            return super.handleError();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the trigger code :

```
trigger DebugLogGenerator on Log__e (after insert) {

    RecordType rt = [Select Id from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Debug_Log__c' and DeveloperName like 'logs'];

    Debug_Log__c[] recordings = new Debug_Log__c[]{};
    for (Log__e le : Trigger.new){
        recordings.add( 
            new Debug_Log__c(
                Data__c = le.Data__c,
                RecordTypeId = le.Log_Type__c == null ? rt.Id : le.Log_Type__c
            )
        );
    }
    insert recordings;
}
```

The same thing which I am doing without a platform event then I am getting the emails through the workflow.

Here is my email alret configuration.

[image]

Comment: What is the email alert's configuration? Per Doug Ayers' answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221708/does-messaging-sendemail-not-work-in-a-platform-event-trigger-context), you'll have to use a default workflow user or Org-Wide Email Address.

Comment: N.B. The value of rt.Id can be obtained using describe methods and does not require a soql call

Comment: @cropredy thanks, I will make that change.

Comment: @DavidReed I have added the email alert's detail here.